# java,Webdriver, I want to fetch all links in a webpage and then compare them to a string name that I have and if it is found then click it

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

java, Webdriver, So now i have this, but the casting in the third line is giving me errors

public void getLinks(String linkName)throws Exception{

```
try { 

    List<WebElement> links = ((Webelement)driver).findElements(By.tagName("a")); 

    for (WebElement myElement : links){ 

        String link = myElement.getText();

        if (link.equals(linkName)){
         myElement.click();
         } 

    } 
 }catch (Exception e){

    System.out.println("Error the link was not found "+e);
```

} 
}

and if i run it this is what i see: Starting ChromeDriver (v2.6.232923) on port 34733
Error the link was not found java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ThreadLocal cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
PASSED: testing

Also my second idea is that it is not finding: “tagName("a"));” for links. But then when I go to the web I see Contacts in Portugal covering Airlines
So the links are in “a” tags, so I don’t think is this.
And im passing this : String linkName= "Contacts in Portugal covering Airlines";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a wrong assertion:

```
if (assertEquals(linkName, myElement)){
    myElement.click();
}
```

.. because linkName is a String, myElement is a WebElement and the assertEquals() return value is not boolean (only void). You can check it with String equals(). For example:

```
if (link.equals(linkName)){
    myElement.click();
}
```

Comment: i have edited my code and you can see above my new situation, ill much apreciate it if you can lend me a hand, thanks